# MySQL: Is Statement cached in Database?

Tags: mysql, database, prepared-statement

I will get some text from another question here:

The `PreparedStatement` is a slightly more powerful version of a `Statement`, and should always be at least as quick and easy to handle as a Statement.
The Prepared Statement may be parametrized

Most relational databases handles a JDBC / SQL query in four steps:

1. Parse the incoming SQL query
2. Compile the SQL query
3. Plan/optimize the data acquisition path
4. Execute the optimized query / acquire and return data

A `Statement` will always proceed through the four steps above for each SQL query sent to the database. A Prepared Statement pre-executes steps (1) - (3) in the execution process above. Thus, when creating a Prepared Statement some pre-optimization is performed immediately. The effect is to lessen the load on the database engine at execution time.

Now here is my question:

If I use hundreds or thousands of `Statement`, will it be cause performance problems in database? (I don't mean that they will perform slower because of more jobs to do every time). Will all those statements be cached in database or they will be lost in space as soon as they are executed?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no restictions on using prepared statements, you should work carefully with them.
As you said you need hundreds of prepaired, think twice may be you are using it wrong.
The pattern it should be used is having an application that doing a haevy inserts/updates/select hundred or thousand times a second which only differs in variables. So in real world it would be like, connecting, creating session, sending statement, and sending bunch of variables to that statement.

But if your plan is to create prepared on each single operations, it's just better to use common queries.

On your questions:

1. Hundreds of statements will not kill mysql or drive you to performance degradation
2. The prepared are stored in memory while client session is up and running. As soon as you close session the prepared die.

To be sure you need it:

1. Your app able to execute statements fast so you get speed value of using them
2. Your query will not have a variable number of arguments, otherwise you can kill you app by creating objects and storing in memory on every statement